# Не происходит сортировка

Tags: c++, сортировка, visual-studio-2017

Задание: 6. Объявите двумерный целочисленный массив, в котором n x n элементов. Отсортируйте по возрастанию заданную строку массива. Распечатайте массив в виде таблицы дважды: до и после сортировки.

Проблема: не могу понять почему не происходит сортировка

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int n = 4; // размер массива
    int arr[n][n];
    cout << "Введите массив:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "arr[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]" << ": ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];  // ввод элементов массива
        }
    }

    cout << "=============================================" << endl;

    cout << "Введенный массив:" << endl; // вывод заполненного массива
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    cout << "=============================================" << endl;

    int choice = 0, temp;
    cout << "Выберите строку, которую вы хотите отсортировать, выберите значение от 0 до 4:" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            if (arr[choice][j] > arr[choice][j] + 1) {
                temp = arr[choice][j];
                arr[choice][j] = arr[choice][j + 1];
                arr[choice][j + 1] = temp;

        }
    }


    cout << "=============================================" << endl;

    cout << "Полученный массив:" << endl; // вывод результата 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну давайте посмотрим... У вас

```
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (arr[choice][j] > arr[choice][j] + 1) {
            temp = arr[choice][j];
            arr[choice][j] = arr[choice][j + 1];
            arr[choice][j + 1] = temp;
    }
```

выполняется один проход по циклу, и идет обмен в парах, где левый больше правого.

Вернее, это вы так думаете, но на самом деле вы проверяете

```
arr[choice][j] > arr[choice][j] + 1
```

Или, вычитая `arr[choice][j]` слева и справа, проверяете `0 > 1`...

Вот ничего и не работает.

И это хорошо! потому что вы пытаетесь вот тут `arr[choice][j + 1];` выбраться за границы массива, что очень нехорошо.

Да и не сработает ваша сортировка... Смотрите, пусть есть

```
5  1  8  15  2
```

Идем, встречаем пару 5-1, меняем

```
1  5  8  15  2
```

Далее пара 5-8, нормальная. Не меняем. Как и пару 8-15. Потом - 15-2, меняем:

```
1  5  8  2  15
```

Все, ваш алгоритм (который вы *хотели* написать) завершен. Фокус не удался...

Это - все ответы на вопрос "**почему** не происходит сортировка".

Как сделать, чтоб происходила? прочесть о разных методах сортировки и написать правильно...